# Calibration of two different camera with different spesification

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

Is it possible to calibrate and combine two different camera that no similiar, one camera is omni directional and one camera is normal camera, i cant find from surfing browser.

Can anyone give some method or recommend book or paper, anything that you think relate to this topic?